# Conditionally replace a value in a matrix with a new value if condition is TRUE

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, replace

I am currently trying to create a new matrix by looping over the old one. The thing that I would want to change in the new matrix is replacing certain values with the character "recoding".Both of the matrixes should have 10 columns and 100 rows.

In the current case, the certain value is one that matches with on eof the values in `vector_A`.

e.g:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  new_matrix[,i] <- old_matrix[,i]
  output_t_or_f <- is.element(new_matrix[,i],unlist(vector_A))
  if (any(output_t_or_f, na.rm = FALSE)) { 
    replace(new_matrix, list = new_matrix[,i], values = "recode")
  }   
}
```

so `output_t_or_f` should either take on the value `TRUE` or `FALSE`, depending on whether i is in vector_A
and if `output_t_or_f` is `TRUE` then the old value should be replaced with the character `"recode"`

Currently the `new_matrix` looks just like the `old_matrix` so I guess there is a problem with the if statement?

Unfortunately, I can't really share my Data but I put some example data together:
if `old_matrix` looks like this:

```
> old_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

and vector_A looks like this:

```
> vector_A
[1] 12 27 30 42 37  9
```

then the new matrix should looks like this:

> new_matrix

```
     [,1] [,2]       [,3]       [,4] [,5]
[1,] "1"  "6"        "11"       "16" "21"
[2,] "2"  "7"        "recoding" "17" "22"
[3,] "3"  "8"        "13"       "18" "23"
[4,] "4"  "recoding" "14"       "19" "24"
[5,] "5"  "10"       "15"       "20" "25"
```

I am very new to R and can't seem to find the problem. Would appreciate any help!!
Thanks :-)

Comment: It would help a lot to see a sample input and desired output -- what do `old_matrix` and `vector_A` look like? We don't need a full 100x10 example, share, say, a 5x3 sample to illustrate the problem.

Comment: `dput()` is a great way to share sample data, `dput(old_matrix[1:5, 1:3])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows and 3 columns of `old_matrix`, including all class and structure information. Choose a suitable small subset that has some values to replace and some to stay the same.

Comment: Thank you very much @GregorThomas! Unfortunately I can't share the data but I put an example together, I hope that helps illustrate the problem :-)

Comment: Are you aware that a matrix can only have one data type, so if you start with a numeric matrix and insert a string into even 1 cell, the entire matrix will be converted to `character` class? That's usually a bad thing. Maybe replacing the values with `NA` instead of `"recoding"` would work better?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that! Actually the original sample (old_matrix) consists of codes which are actually characters (because I made the example in a hurry I just chose numbers). In this case, it's completely fine for everything to be in characters. Unfortunately I can't really replace with NA, because there are some actual NAs in the data as well. And I  don't think I would be able to do that, because my current problem is finding the values and replacing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the replacements are the same in every column you shouldn't need a loop. Try this:

```
new_matrix <- old_matrix
new_matrix[new_matrix %in% vector_A] <- "recode"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe it was this easy! I guess I got too much into the details and forgot about the basics... You really saved me :-)